# Java = Download Buffer not filled fully? How does flusing/Buffering work?

Tags: java, stream, io, buffer

I want to monitor the progress of downloading data. I want to log after a certain amount of data has been transferred. My Code:

```
int contentLength = 0;
final int bufferSize = 1024*8;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int length = 0;

while ( (length = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer) ) !=-1 ) {
    contentLength = contentLength+length;

    if ( (contentLength % (bufferSize*1024*4)) ==0 ) {
                logger.debug(contentLength);
    }   
}
```

This seemed to be not working. It seems that the buffer is not always full and therefore a multiple of the buffersize that is used as modulo does not match.

Is this really common that the buffer is not "full"? How can this happen? What is the internal logic that a bufer is "flushed"? Does Java wait for s specific time to receive packets and then flush (if the buffer is not full)? Any information how this internally works would be great for understanding it.

(I do not need a solution, I have implemented it other, just wondering if this is common that the buffer is never fully read? And would be curious to understand why.)

Thanks very much!
Jens

Answer (score 1):

It's very common that a read operation on a socket will not fill the buffer exactly. The sender is flushing packets of various length. These then pass through layers of applications, operating systems, and networks that may fragment them. The typical result is partial buffer reads.

I generally size my read buffer to match the [socket's read buffer,](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getReceiveBufferSize%28%29) which acts as a *maximum* size, but I never rely on it getting filled every time.

Also, you should note that it's inefficient to use `BufferedInputStream` when you are performing bulk reads (into a byte array). It just adds the overhead of copying data from array to array. It is also one of the sources of fragmentation mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that buffer would be full. These are specifics of IO. You must use return value of `read` to determine how much data was actually read.

Answer (score 0):

When you can the `read(byte[], ...)` API, the stream will try to fill the allocated space in the buffer. But it won't always fill it. Certainly, if the content in the stream runs out, it cannot fill the entire space. But there are also other reasons. A stream implementation may use some background thread to fetch data, for example. If the read call is passed down to the operating system, it may read one block of data at a time. If the stream is buffered, and the buffer still has some content, it may just return what is left in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively dependent on the actual `InputStream` you used and boils down to "how does the OS handle `read()` calls".

On most modern operating systems the basic `read` call does the same thing: It attempts to read as much data as was requested but may stop earlier.

This can easily happen when your buffer is larger than the read-ahead buffer of the filesystem. Or when you're reading from a network connection and just a few packets have arrived yet.

Some devices have pretty predictive behaviour (reading from the file systems *tends* to fill the provided buffer fully if it's not to big, reading from the network leaves it half-filled more often). But you can't depend on it one way or another.

So: yes, it can easily happen.